# MySql and regular expressions

Tags: mysql, regex

Does anybody know how to either get a bit more detailed error message wrt MySql and regular expressions (i.e. the character position where the problem occurs) or if there is a tool that you can use to try out regular expressions without the need to trial and error with the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) can do this (and it's one of the few tools you can use to debug regexes in the MySQL-specific syntax).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I was hoping for something free (being rather skint at the moment :-( )

Comment: +1 RegexBuddy rocks. But don't take my word for it - Read: [Jeff's RegexBuddy blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/07/my-buddy-regex.html). If you are using regex, this tool is _very_ helpful (and pays for itself in no time flat)!